# Unable to find mistake in computing this integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification, residue-calculus

This question is from Ponnusamy and Silvermann's Complex analysis section - evaluation of real integrals (page 330) and I am making a mistake in the method because my answers is not matching with the answer given.

> Question: For each integer $n$, $\displaystyle \int_{|z|=n} \tan(\pi z) \, \mathrm{d}z $.
>
> Answer given: $2-4ni$

Attempt: At odd integers $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ there is a singularity at $m/2$. Also, such odd $m$ can be written as $m=2p+1$, so there is a singularity at each $\left|\frac{2p+1}{2}\right| < n $.

$$\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{m/2} = \lim_{z \to m/2} (z-m/2)\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{\sin(\pi z)}$$

and as $\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{\sin(\pi z)}$ is indeterminate so I used L'Hospital rule and got $0$.

Can you please tell what mistake I was making because I am getting wrong answer.

Comment: L'Hopital doesn't work because $\tan(m\pi/2)$ is of the form $\frac{\pm 1}0$ for odd integers $m$ which is not an indeterminate form.

Comment: And your formula for the residue is not correct. You should have $$\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=m/2}\tan(\pi z) = \lim_{z \to m/2} \bigl(z - \tfrac{m}{2}\bigr) \tan(\pi z), $$ since $m/2$ is a simple pole of $\tan(\pi z)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee ya that's a typo. I know the exact formula.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas So, Can you please tell how to solve it in right manner